# Get folder nodeRef by lucene search

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Is there a possibility to get a nodeRef of Alfresco folder by using: `search.luceneSearch("PATH_OF_THE_FOLDER")`

Comment: I've seen something like this:
`var result = search.luceneSearch('PATH:"PATH_OF_THE_FOLDER"');
log.warn(result[0].nodeRef);`

Comment: Your solution works fine. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to call findNode for each result, because the luceneSearch call returns an array of nodes.

If you know your query returns a single node, you can do this:

```
var folder;
var nodes = search.luceneSearch("PATH:\"/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:StarXpert_x0020_Workflow\"");
folder = nodes[0];
```

Comment: Yes, i used this to resolve my issue, i forgot to update my response. Thanks Jeff

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.
`search.luceneSearch("PATH_OF_THE_FOLDER")` returns a list of an objects, so i looped over this list and get the `nodeRef` of the element of the list like this:

```
var folder;
var nodes = search.luceneSearch("PATH:\"/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:StarXpert_x0020_Workflow\"");
for each(node in nodes){
    folder=search.findNode(node.nodeRef);
}
```

So now in `folder` i have the `nodeRef` of the single node returned by `luceneSearch`.